# How to change every word on website to another?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a script that changes word/phrases on website to any other given by user. It needs to be done after user will put a first and second word to a form and execute it by clicking a button.

I want to use pure JS only. Can anyone help me?

```js
function changeWord() {
  var fromWord = getElementById("inputText1");
  var toWord = getElementById("inputText2");
  var str = document.getElementsByTagName("body").innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(var fromWord, var toWord);
  document.getElementById("body").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="inputText" id="inputText1" placeholder="Change from">
<input type="text" name="inputText" id="inputText2" placeholder="To">
<button onclick="changeWord()">Execute</button>

<p> Here is a text. </p>

<p> Here is another text </p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by website? Some other website than the one the user is currently on? Some other page than the user is currently on?

Comment: I have to ask why do you want to use pure JS only?

Comment: As you can see from the snippet I made, you have errors stemming from the `(var fromword, var toWord)`

Comment: Also you do not have anything with ID=body - you want to have a span or div with id="result" and use `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = res;`

Comment: By website I mean whole page that user is currently on. I use pure JS for now only, cause I am begginer.

Comment: you are missing document in front of document.getElementById

Comment: You are missing the [0] in the document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML because it returns a nodelist

Comment: You are missing the value in `document.getElementById("inputText1").value;`  - same for the second field

Comment: The replace is not replacing all occurrences - `var res = str.split(fromWord).join(toWord);` would work better, but if that word is input or button, you will break the text

Comment: I changed a code a bit using your instructions but something is still not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rbdscfoy/